# Use Asp.net MVC1 or MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

A project is due to be started and finished by the end of the year. It's for internal company use, will be entirely done by a single developer(me). I intend to make use of data annotations(via [Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx)) and [xVal](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/01/10/xval-a-validation-framework-for-aspnet-mvc/) for the first time.

It's a 2-3 page web app to collect defect information. It was started in asp.net without a master page, and would be far better off with one for consistency. The model layer was developed as a separate project in its own assembly. The existing solution feeds in fake data and saves to memory only, so the persistance layer is not present yet.

**Is it safe to jump into asp.net MVC2? Or do I need to stick to mvc 1 for some reason?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754106/should-i-start-on-asp-net-mvc-1-or-mvc-2-beta/1754865#1754865 .. hope this helps

Comment: Its throws some light on what you are trying to figure out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 does come with a "go live" license, neither it nor MVC2 are actually 'ready' for production use. Building things with MVC1 now and later upgrading to MVC2 shouldn't be all that difficult, and since it's an internal project, it might actually be better if all of your developers have not gotten up to speed on VS2010.

If there is no pushing technical reason to goto MVC2, I'd say just stick to version 1 for now.

Have fun with the new project, it's a rare thing to have happen in the corporate world.

Comment: my department is almost entirely small greenfield projects, and I get to write my own ticket about which visual studio/microsoft technologies to utilize.

Answer (score 1):

I started with Asp.Net MVC 1 by version ctp 2 for a production site, it worked great, no bugs or anything, but there was quite a pain when a new version of Asp.Net MVC was released as they seldom were backward compatible.

Many new shiny things which are available in MVC 2 are possible to get via Asp.Net MVC Futures and MvcContrib.

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar in the past. Started with MVC beta and moved to MVC 1 prior to release.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was debating this myself for a little. The thing that kept me to MVC 1 atm is all the other libraries that I use. I don't know what state everything is at in supporting MVC 2, but that is definitely what tipped the decision to stay with MVC 1.

For an MVC 1 project a while back I did a similar thing with data annotations and jQuery Validate. So you can always roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

We went to MVC2 because we needed support for [Single-Project Areas](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx).